# Sorting an XamDataGrid by multiple columns

Tags: infragistics, xamdatagrid

Can someone point me to an example in code for sorting a XamDataGrid by multiple columns, such as 
columnA desc, then columnB asc

thanks
Oskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://news.infragistics.com/forums/p/52894/275217.aspx#275217